# Error after pip upgrade using command "pip3 install --upgrade pip"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip

My python library pandas,numpy, matplotlib are worked earlier, now I use command 
`pip3 install --upgrade pip` for upgrade pip and next "`import pandas` command is not working".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/home/desktop/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['/home/desktop/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version.
```

And next i trying to install pandas using command sudo pip3 install pandas , i get following error

```
desktop@desktop-All-Series:~$ sudo pip3 install pandas
WARNING: The directory '/home/desktop/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/home/desktop/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (0.25.3)
ERROR: Package 'pandas' requires a different Python: 3.5.2 not in '>=3.5.3'

desktop@desktop-All-Series:~$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It says that pip3 not supporting.
You can use this command. 
just try,

```
conda install pandas
```

and try this cmd also

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working now after using command

```
python3 -m pip install pandas --user

desktop@desktop-All-Series:~$ python3 -m pip install pandas --user
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/24/0cdbf8907e1e3bc5a8da03345c23cbed7044330bb8f73bb12e711a640a00/pandas-0.24.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Collecting numpy>=1.12.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/e9/2561dbfbc05146bffa02167e09b9902e273decb2dc4cd5c43314ede20312/numpy-1.17.4-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.13.0)
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.11.1
    Uninstalling numpy-1.11.1:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.11.1
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.5 are installed in '/home/desktop/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed numpy-1.17.4 pandas-0.24.2
```